# Wildfly server-provisioning missing jar

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

I'm trying to use the latest version of hibernate-search in Wildfly13. I made sure to follow the direction from hibernate's documentation on server provisioning: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-deploy-on-wildfly.

The specified maven plugin created a wildfly-with-updated-hibernate-search folder in the project's target folder. I copied the modules folder to my WF_HOME/modules. It contains the 5.3 module.xml version of the hibernate jar but is missing all the jars. Thus throwing some "Failed to define class exception".

Do I need to download the missing jars one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. We need to explicitly set the property copy-module-artifacts to true in server-provisioning XML configuration.

```
<server-provisioning xmlns="urn:wildfly:server-provisioning:1.1" copy-module-artifacts="true">
```

That did the trick for me.